# powershell curl and WebRequest both follow redirects

Tags: powershell, curl, webrequest

I was trying to figure out the status code returned by my webpage, which most certainly is 301 (moved permanently), according to curl on the Linux subsystem, but using curl or the WebRequest object on powershell, it returns 200 (OK).

Why is this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is because .NET and PowerShell are following redirects by default but curl does not do this. The default value of `HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect` is true and Invoke-WebRequest's MaximumRedirection default value is 5.

To turn off automatic redirection via WebRequest:

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://google.com")
$request.AllowAutoRedirect = $false
$request.GetResponse()
```

or Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://google.com" -MaximumRedirection 0
```

Alternatively, use the -L flag to follow redirects in curl:

```
curl -L google.com
```

Comment: PowerShell's curl alias using `-MaximumRedirection 0` causes an error. Add `-ErrorAction Ignore` to actually see the response.

Comment: @Dan What version of PowerShell are you using? My machine has 5.1.17134.407 and it is not throwing any error.

Comment: @Franklin, I'm currently using the same version and now the `-MaximumRedirection 0` switch will show redirection response as well as the "maximum redirection count has been exceeded" message.

Comment: Note that [this will not help in PowerShell 6.0](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/pull/3442) (AKA PowerShell Core).

Comment: Thank you for this

Comment: In addition: the -MaximumRedirection also works for Invoke-RestMethod.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest http://minnesota.publicradio.org/tools/podcasts/song_of_the_day.xml -MaximumRedirection 8 -Verbose` doesn't redirect for me like `curl -vL http://minnesota.publicradio.org/tools/podcasts/song_of_the_day.xml` does.

Comment: For me, PowerShell 5.1 threw the "Maximum Redirection count has been exceeded" error for a 301 redirect but it did *not* for a 303 redirect.  I haven't had a chance to test it with a 302 redirect.