# Invoke-WebRequest is unable to POST data on Single Page App (1 URI) and KeepAlive is disabled

Tags: powershell, cookies, httprequest, keep-alive

### TL;DR

I need to submit multiple forms on a site that reloads pages but the server closes session after every request on a single page app that only has one URL and I think this is preventing my POST method from going through. The main problem is every request uses the first state of the page and I can't get to states farther in the process.

### What I'm trying to accomplish

I am trying to automate a process that requires me to go to take the following steps in order:

1. Navigate to webpage. (GET)
2. Click on a button that reloads the page with new data but uses same URL. (POST)
3. Enter text into a field on new page.
4. Click on the form to submit the text. (POST)
5. ... perform unrelated admin tasks....

I'm trying to automate this process using the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet in PowerShell following steps similar to those found in the [PowerShell Cookbook](http://www.powershellcookbook.com/recipe/vODQ/script-a-web-application-session) regarding FaceBook login.

When I run an `Invoke-WebRequest` from a completely fresh PowerShell Session I get a response but I can't reuse that session ever again. To make another request I need to create a new `-SessionVariable` or use `-DisableKeepAlive`.

The server will always return a `connection close` in the response no matter what even though it is using http 1.1 and it's not my site so I can' change this.

So how can I go about establishing a connection to the server that I can reuse to POST the form data? I feel like it should be doable because it is clearly happening on the WebPage itself.

When I go to the WebPage, open the Developer Tools in Chrome and step through the process the header contains this in the Form Data field:

**RAW**

```
ggt_textbox%2810007%29=&action=adminloginbtn&ggt_hidden%2810008%29=2
```

**PARSED and DECODED**

```
ggt_textbox(10007):
action:adminloginbtn
ggt_hidden(10008):2
```

If I try to do something like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest $uri -SessionVariable session -Verbose -Method POST -Body "ggt_textbox%2810007%29=&action=adminloginbtn" -DisableKeepAlive
```

It returns the page I'm expecting in step 2. So I performed steps 3 and 4 in Chrome to try and do the same thing. I get the the following Form Data in Chrome Dev Tools:

**RAW**

ggt_textbox%2810006%29=textIentered&action=loginbtn&ggt_hidden%2810008%29=3

**PARSED**

```
ggt_textbox(10006):textIentered
action:loginbtn
ggt_hidden(10008):3
```

So that made me think I could do something like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest $uri -WebSession $session -Verbose -Method POST -Body "ggt_textbox%2810006%29=textIentered&action=loginbtn&ggt_hidden%2810008%29=3"# -DisableKeepAlive
```

But since the main page and the login page use the same URI it tries to POST to a form that doesn't exist because it's looking at the very first page.

I did some more digging and found when I perform this same action from the webpage itself it returns a `302 Moved Temporarily` status code the response header actually has a cookie in it (still closes the connection) which is a first and then appears to do a GET request using the new cookie and I'm now logged into the admin page.

So I think I have two problems I need to get around:

1. How can I get to the form that exists after I click the first button since they use the same URI?
2. <strike>How can I get around the 302 status since I'm only getting back a header and nothing else. I think I need to do a GET request using the cookie from the header but I'm not sure how to specify a cookie with Invoke-WebRequest. I think I would need to use the `-Header` parameter and specify `Cookie: COOKIENAME=CookieID`</strike>

I think most of all I need to get through my first question  <strike>and then from there I can start working towards my second.</strike>

All help is appreciated and I can provide any header/source needed but the web page is super simple so there is not a whole lot going on in the front end other than a couple of buttons and a logo with a little bit of inline JavaScript.

### EDIT

After doing some additional reading about 302 and redirects I found out that shouldn't be a problem. The reason for this is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156458/powershell-curl-and-webrequest-both-follow-redirects).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. The inline JavaScript is validating to make sure the length of the string is greater than 0 before submitting the login. I don't think there is away to by pass the client side validation easily in a script.